# Why doesn't echo support "\e" (escape) when using the -e argument in MacOSX

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, bash

When I try to print out some colored text using ANSI escape sequences via the built-in `echo` command, it seems that the `\e` escape sequence in the string I provide is interpreted literally instead of as the "escape" it's supposed to represent. This only happens in Snow Leopard -- the examples below work as intended in Leopard.

Apparently `echo` does support the `-e` switch since it correctly interprets `\n` when using it:

```
~ $ 
~ $ echo "\n"
\n
~ $ echo -e "\n"


~ $
```

But when I try to use `\e`, I get this:

```
~ $ echo -e "\e[34mCOLORS"
\e[34mCOLORS
~ $
```

Like I said, in Leopard, the above would give me the string "COLORS" in color.

Does anyone know of a reason why this might be an intended change? How about a workaround for printing ANSI escape sequences from Bash scripts on Snow Leopard?

The Bash shell version on my Leopard machine is `3.2.17(1)-release` and `3.2.48(1)-release` on my Snow Leopard machine.

Comment: The question contradicts the post. In the question you refer to /bin/echo, while in the post you use echo without path, which most probably is the builtin echo of your shell.

Comment: Of course -- thanks for noticing. I fixed the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I cannot tell you why it does not support that argument (you may have to ask the programmers about that).
I only know that on my linux box, I get this:

```
$ /bin/echo --help
Usage: /bin/echo [SHORT-OPTION]... [STRING]...
  or:  /bin/echo LONG-OPTION
Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

  -n             do not output the trailing newline
  -e             enable interpretation of backslash escapes
  -E             disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
*emphasized text*
  \0NNN   the character whose ASCII code is NNN (octal)
  \\     backslash
  \a     alert (BEL)
  \b     backspace
  \c     produce no further output
  \f     form feed
  \n     new line
  \r     carriage return
  \t     horizontal tab
  \v     vertical tab

NOTE: your shell may have its own version of echo, which usually supersedes
the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation
for details about the options it supports.

Report echo bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
Report echo translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
```

- this does not mention `\e` escapes
- it says that it is `/bin/echo` from gnu coreutils. As apple changes the source of their unix-system components from time to time (e.g. move from zsh to bash), check if there was a change for `/bin/echo` between Leopard and Snow Leopard. If it is gnu, you can ask the people at gnu.org why they choose not to include those sequences.

As for workarounds (thats more interesting):
Not using `/bin/echo`, but bash's builtin `echo` works on linux boxes. If they changed to a bash without builtin echo (or something even more obscure), you could also try this not widely known feature of your shell (works at least in bash and zsh):

```
$ echo $'\e[34m''COLORS'
```

This is the matching part of bash's manpage:

```
   Words  of  the  form  $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with
   backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI  C  standard.   Backslash
   escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
          \a     alert (bell)
          \b     backspace
          \e     an escape character
          \f     form feed
          \n     new line
          \r     carriage return
          \t     horizontal tab
          \v     vertical tab
          \\     backslash
          \'     single quote
          \nnn   the  eight-bit  character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three
                 digits)
          \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value  HH  (one  or
                 two hex digits)
          \cx    a control-x character

   The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

   A  double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($) will cause the string to be trans‐
   lated according to the current locale.  If the current locale is C or POSIX, the  dollar
   sign  is  ignored.  If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-
   quoted.
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `$'string'` being escape sequence -enabled, thanks.

Comment: `\e` is not part of the POSIX standard; the GNU coreutils implementation extended on the standard. OS X did not.

Comment: Every day, MacOS befuddles me beyond measure.

Answer (score 53):

Try `\x1B` instead of `\e`.

Comment: Just for reference, `1B` is the hex value of the [Escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character).

Answer (score 17):

Does `\033` still work? If not, you can hopefully press Ctrl+V followed by the Escape key (if a mac has those keys) to create a real control character inside the command line (which does not work that well in scripts of course, depending on the editor)

Comment: Just for reference, `33` is the octal value of the [Escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character).

Comment: Just for future reader reference `033` would be _standardised_ way to write octal.

Comment: or just write it as `\33` there's no ambiguity whatsoever

Answer (score 11):

One other way of printing ANSI escape sequences in the shell is by using [`/usr/bin/printf`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/printf.1.html).

Comment: printf is the portable way of displaying things in shell. There are too many flavours of echo...

Answer (score 9):

To complement the existing helpful answers with some **background information**:

If you're **invoking `echo` by *name* only** - as opposed to with its path, `/bin/echo` - **you're invoking the Bash *builtin*** rather than the external utility.

The behavior of native Bash elements such as builtins is typically portable in a Bash sense, meaning *they should work the same on any platform capable of running Bash*.

**`\e` is a curious exception that affects the stock 3.x Bash version on macOS** (which, for legal reasons won't change, and macOS has since officially made `zsh` its default shell).

`\e` (and its alias `\E`) ***should* work with `echo -e`**, given that **`\e` support was added to the `echo` builtin in [Bash 2.0](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS).**, but inexplicably ***doesn't* in the 3.x stock version on macOS**.

`\e` *does* work in 3.x Bash versions on *other* platforms, such as MSYS on Windows.

Conversely, **if you install and use Bash v4+ on macOS**, e.g. via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), **`\e` *does* work.**

Answer (score 2):

They might try to conform to POSIX:
http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Part OPTIONS states among other things:

```
Implementations shall not support any options.
```

Comment: Here is the direct link to the material I think you intended: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: Nope. The page continues to write: ‘If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.’ Also, the macOS echo does interpret `-e`.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, We're just about to add \e support to /bin/echo and /usr/bin/printf in coreutils.
Note the C standards do not specify \e, but gcc, perl, bash, ksh and tcsh support it

Answer (score 0):

You might check if ,,escape non-ascii characters'' have been un-checked in the view options menu of the terminal.app.